# Using adb to launch apps - using file as input and lacking activity name?

Tags: android, adb

I would like to be able to launch specific apps over adb, reading them from a file.

For example - say I wish to launch 'com.ebay.mobile'. I have a file that has simply 'com.ebay.mobile' as the contents, and I'd then like to use a batch file to launch the contents of that file, for instance filling the rest of the command.

Obviously, this runs into difficulty with the lack of an activity name, so additionally, would it also be possible for the app to launch without specifying this, so the default activity launches?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are many ways to find out the activity name. Or you could just run `monkey -p your.package.name 1`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following 2 commands (you need to use both) to run an app - if you don't specify an Activity, it will use the Main one defined in the AndroidManifest file.

```
adb install yourAPKFile.apk

adn run com.your.package
```

Comment: 'adb run' doesn't seem to work, unfortunately!

Additionally, what I meant was, that the file simply contains the text 'com.ebay.mobile' (as the example) which can then be used to complete the command adb start am etc etc. I'm just not sure how to do this, or indeed, if it's possible to do it without specifying anything else.